# Travis CI Spring Boot Error (Gradle Error)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, travis-ci

I am having trouble with running my Travis Ci. I am getting below error for my spring boot application.

```
0.01s$ java -Xmx32m -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
$ javac -J-Xmx32m -version
javac 11.0.2
3.37s$ ./gradlew assemble
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
The command "eval ./gradlew assemble " failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
The command "eval ./gradlew assemble " failed. Retrying, 3 of 3.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
The command "eval ./gradlew assemble " failed 3 times.
The command "./gradlew assemble" failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

`.travis.yml` file

```
language: java
sudo: false
script: mvn clean verify
```

Let me know which files you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the problem was that somehow my Spring-boot application has both Maven and Gradle files. I believe, while me experimenting different things, I generated Gradew file hence Travis CI was looking for Gradle.

Solution was to remove all the gradle files and re-run travis. I have updated my travis.yml as below

```
jdk:
    - oraclejdk8

# would just use default install/script but the ./mvnw script errors on travis
# obviously this only works for maven builds right now...
install:
    - mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V
    - mvn cobertura:cobertura

script:
    - mvn test

dist: trusty

after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash) -t
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to check in the files in gradle/wrapper. It should have two files `gradle-wrapper.jar` and `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Comment: Thats true. How do i build this files?

Comment: You will need to download a distribution of Gradle, if you don't have one already. Then type `gradle wrapper` (notice the missing 'w').

Comment: Even though it is maven project?

Comment: I don't know, but somewhere you are invoking `./gradlew assemble` as you can see from the output. Maybe your Maven build is invoking Gradle for some sub-projet, though that sounds weird.